# Login not going to HomeScreen

Tags: reactjs, react-native, fetch

My login not going to `HomeScreen`, but when I reload the app it will automatically go to `HomeScreen`? The login functionality works fine the only thing that bugging me right now, it needs to reload the app before it will go to `HomeScreen`.

Below are the file for my `App`, `LoadingScreen`, `LoginScreen`, and `HomeScreen`.

`App.js`

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import SignupScreen from './screens/SignupScreen';
import LoginScreen from './screens/LoginScreen';
import LoadingScreen from './screens/LoadingScreen';
import HomeSceen from './screens/HomeScreen';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';


const App = ({ navigation }) => {
  const [isloggedin, setLogged] = useState(null);
  const detectLogin = async () => {
    const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('token');
    if (token !== null) {
      setLogged(true);
    } else {
      setLogged(false);
    }
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    detectLogin();
  }, []);

  const StackApp = createStackNavigator();

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <StackApp.Navigator headerMode="none">
        <StackApp.Screen name="loading" component={LoadingScreen} />
        <StackApp.Screen name="home" component={HomeSceen} />
        <StackApp.Screen name="login" component={LoginScreen} />
        <StackApp.Screen name="signup" component={SignupScreen} />
      </StackApp.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

export default App;
```

`LoadingScreen.js`

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import {
  ActivityIndicator,
  View,
  StyleSheet
} from 'react-native';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';

const LoadingScreen = (props) => {

  const detectLogin = async () => {
    const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('token');
    if (token) {
      props.navigation.replace("home");
    } else {
      props.navigation.replace("login");
    }
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    detectLogin();
  }, []);

  return (
    <View style={styles.loading}>
      <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#ff0550" />
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  loading: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center"
  },
});

export default LoadingScreen;
```

`LoginScreen.js`

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Button, TextInput } from 'react-native-paper';
import {
  View,
  Text,
  StatusBar,
  TouchableOpacity,
  KeyboardAvoidingView,
  Alert,
} from 'react-native';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';
import { SafeAreaView } from 'react-native-safe-area-context';


const LoginScreen = (props) => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');

  const handleLogin = async (props) => {
    fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/auth/login', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        'email': email,
        'password': password,
      }),
    })
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(async (data) => {
        try {
          const items = [['token', data.token], ['user', data.user._id]];
          AsyncStorage.multiSet(items);
          props.navigation.replace('home');
        } catch (e) {
          console.log('error log', data.error);
          Alert(data.error);
        }
      });
  };

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior="position">
        <StatusBar backgroundColor="#ff0550" barStyle="light-content" />
        <View
          style={{
            borderBottomColor: '#ff0550',
            borderBottomWidth: 4,
            borderRadius: 10,
            marginLeft: 20,
            marginRight: 150,
            marginTop: 4,
          }}
        />
        <Text
          style={{
            fontSize: 20, marginLeft: 18, marginTop: 20
          }}

        >Login with email</Text>
        <TextInput
          label='Email'
          autoCapitalize="none"
          mode="outlined"
          value={email}
          style={{ marginLeft: 18, marginRight: 18, marginTop: 18 }}
          theme={{ colors: { primary: '#ff0550' } }}
          onChangeText={(text) => setEmail(text)}

        />
        <TextInput
          label='password'
          autoCapitalize="none"
          mode="outlined"
          secureTextEntry={true}
          value={password}
          onChangeText={(text) => { setPassword(text) }}
          style={{ marginLeft: 18, marginRight: 18, marginTop: 18 }}
          theme={{ colors: { primary: '#ff0550' } }}

        />
        <Button
          mode="contained"
          style={{ marginLeft: 18, marginRight: 18, marginTop: 18, backgroundColor: '#ff0550' }}
          onPress={() => handleLogin(props)}>
          Login
      </Button>
        <TouchableOpacity>
          <Text
            style={{
              fontSize: 18, marginLeft: 18, marginTop: 20
            }}
            onPress={() => props.navigation.replace('signup')}
          >dont have a account ?</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>

      </KeyboardAvoidingView>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};



export default LoginScreen;
```

`HomeScreen.js`

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Button } from 'react-native-paper';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';

const HomeScreen = (props) => {

  const logout = (props) => {
    let keys = ['user', 'token'];
    AsyncStorage.multiRemove(keys, (error) => {
      props.navigation.replace('login');
    });
  };

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, marginTop: 100 }}>
      <Text style={{ fontSize: 18 }}>your email is sample here!</Text>
      <Button
        mode="contained"
        style={{ marginLeft: 18, marginRight: 18, marginTop: 18, backgroundColor: '#ff0550' }}
        onPress={() => logout(props)}
      >
        logout
      </Button>
    </View>
  );
};

export default HomeScreen;
```

Comment: where do you set initial screen? "loading"?
after login request you redirect only to `props.navigation.replace('home');`
and on home page you don't have way to redirect from it or some blocker to open it.
The only one reason why it can't open home page is error on fetch request.
And one more question, do you use isloggedin anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

user props.navigation.navigate("Homescreen")
Also,you need add condition in app js if logged then go to homescreen else login page.
Check switch Navigator too from react-navigation
Replace just change current screen to another screen instead of navigating through screen. so it will stay that screen only